# TSLint: Ban usage of the Function.length property

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm in a project that uses knockout.js (using TypeScript), and since knockout observables are just functions, people often run into issues accessing the `length` property of the observable function by mistake, instead of accessing the `length` property of their custom object model.

Is there some tslint rule that can ban the usage of a specific property of a certain type? I've seen the "ban" rule, but that seems to only work for banning usage of functions and methods, but not properties.

Comment: still couldn't find a solution. Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score -1):

There is a tslint rule that bans the use of specific functions or global methods.

A list of banned functions or methods in the following format:

- banning functions:

  - just the name of the function: "functionName"
  - the name of the function in an array with one element: ["functionName"]
  - an object in the following format: `{"name": "functionName", "message": "optional explanation message"}`
- banning methods:

  - an array with the object name, method name and optional message: `["functionName", "methodName", "optional message"]`
  - an object in the following format: `{"name": ["objectName", "methodName"], "message": "optional message"}`

    > - you can also ban deeply nested methods: `{"name": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}` bans foo.bar.baz()
    > - the first element can contain a wildcard (*) that matches everything. `{"name": ["*", "forEach"]}` bans `[].forEach(...), $(...).forEach(...), arr.forEach(...), etc.`

Config examples

```
"ban": [
  true,
  "eval",
  {"name": "$", "message": "please don't"},
  ["describe", "only"],
  {"name": ["it", "only"], "message": "don't focus tests"},
  {
    "name": ["chai", "assert", "equal"],
    "message": "Use 'strictEqual' instead."
  },
  {"name": ["*", "forEach"], "message": "Use a regular for loop instead."}
]
```

Schema

```
{
  "type": "list",
  "listType": {
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "minLength": 1,
        "maxLength": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "minLength": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "name"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the original question, I'm aware of this rule, but that seems to target functions and methods, but not normal properties, correct? Or can this be used to ban `Function.length` too?

Comment: Right now, `eslint-plugin-ban` [only applies to call expressions](https://github.com/remithomas/eslint-plugin-ban/blob/721a64d0459396d1d0620b907e231522ba4c2a2f/lib/rules/ban.js#L144).